# Can't read global variables from .submit(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, scope

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prova HTML5</title>

        ...

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            va = new Array();
            $(function(){               
                $('#ing').focus();              
                $('#prompt').submit(function() {
                    va.push($('#ing').val());
                    alert(va);
                });
            });            
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="prompt">
            <input type="text" id="ing" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i press enter to submit the form, the alert message says that `va` value is the text that there is in the input box... it seems that it can't read that before it was an array... maybe a problem with scope?

Maybe is a problem with scope?

Comment: Is there a reason you need it in the global scope?

Comment: I'm having trouble following the question.  What is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: i want that when i press enter it pushes in the array the value of the input box

Comment: It works for me: [working example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnUTa/) My guess is that your jquery.js file might be not working.

Comment: no. it works the first time, the second time the array seems to be resetted... try to submit the form more than one time...

with .click it works, when i put .submit the arrays resets automatically!

it should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hgnUV/, but with the .submit event...

Comment: I updated jsfiddle code by adding `return false` [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/LnUTa/1/) is this what you`re looking for?

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code that has to do with this situation? Do you not use `va` anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
        $(function(){      
            va = new Array();         
            $('#ing').focus();              
            $('#prompt').submit(function() {
                va.push($('#ing').val());
                alert(va);
            });
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't work, already tried...
if i change the event with (eg.) click it works...

Comment: @user824963 try using `var va=new array()`

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
va = new Array();
$(function(){               
    $('#ing').focus();              
    $('#prompt').submit(function() {
        window.va.push($('#ing').val());
        alert(window.va);
    });
});
```